# Oracle PL/SQL bad bind variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, database-trigger

I checked all my fields and everything is fine but i keep on getting this error 
When i write this trigger on sql command it says trigger has been created but when i checked on the trigger it showed invalid 
This is my trigger

```
create or replace trigger "Max_Crew_T1"
   Before insert or update on "CREW"
   for each row 
declare 
   v_count number;
Begin
   select count(*) into v_count from CREW where AirPlaneID=:NEW.AirPlaneID;
   if 
      v_count > 5
   then
      Raise_Application_ERROR(-20343,'Crew number exceeded');
   END IF;
END;
```

HERE IS THE ERROR MESSAGE;

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.AIRPLANEID'
```

click on the link below for table desc

[image]

Comment: You may want to add a `show errors;` at the end to see what the actual error is.

Comment: @gvenzl Edited the error i am getting into my question

Comment: Your trigger has another issue: you should not access the same table whose modification fired the trigger. 
 It goes well if you just insert one record at a time, so you are accessing the table (with the select count(*)) before it has already been changed... but it is technically possible to insert multiple rows with the same statement (using a "insert... select" statement). In this case the trigger will run correctly only for the first row, but when it is fired for the second row in the same statement you will get a "table is mutating" error. I suggest you to read about "compound triggers"

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you defined the airplane id while creating the table in quotes. I.e "AirPlaneID" hence you need to do the same in the trigger.

It is not a good practice to define case-sensitive columns with quotes as it causes all these issues, its much better to define without quotes eg. create table crew (airplaneid number(6))..etc. Anyway..

Please use below:

```
create or replace trigger "Max_Crew_T1"
   Before insert or update on "CREW"
   for each row 
declare 
   v_count number;
Begin
   select count(*) into v_count from CREW where "AirPlaneID"=:NEW."AirPlaneID";
   if 
      v_count > 5
   then
      Raise_Application_ERROR(-20343,'Crew number exceeded');
   END IF;
END;
```